# How to send Email through ASP.net using localhost

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a banking application in asp.net v 2.0.I need to send confirmation email when a user creates the new account.

I am running the application in localhost.DO I need any special rights to send SMTP email?

provide me a proper way to send email from my application.

Regards
Jeyaganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a SMTP server set up on localhost?  Test by using telnet on the server:

telnet 127.0.0.1 25

If the server responds, try sending raw SMTP commands to send an email and trouble-shoot from there.

I find the easiest way with the Microsoft SMTP server is to disable any checks for authentication and rely on relay restrictions, then restrict relaying to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I am using my official system.My company network is restricted,I will try your tip.

Comment: I have tried telnet 127.0.0.1.25,the esmtp server works fine.when even I try to send mail from application,I get error,"unable to connect to remote server".Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to send an email using raw SMTP commands? Use the directions at http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html to send an email via telnet. If that works, your problem is likely the server configuration.  If not, it is likely firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're running on localhost shouldn't make any difference.

As long as you have valid email server settings, and it's allowed on the system you are running on, this works just fine.

Did you try it? Did you have a problem?

Comment: Thanks jonathan, I need a valid email server settings.I donno how to use it,Can you help me out

Comment: You need to have your email server and logon credentials. Obviously, there is no way I can provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sent by gmail smtp server. check this out

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/send-email-using-gmail-in-aspnet.html